# Proper way to call RESTful service from angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, rest

I am trying to do a simple todo app with RESTful api. My restful service returns the below JSON,

```
[{"title":"completed this","completed":false},{"title":"and this too","completed":false}]
```

Returned as a application/json not a string.

My view is as below,

```
<div class="container" ng-app="todomvc">
        <div id="todoapp" ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
             <div class="row" ng-repeat="todo in todos">         
             {{todo.title}}
             </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

And I have the below JS code with controller and a factory,

```
var todomvc = angular.module('todomvc', []);

todomvc.factory('todoREST', function ($q,$http) {
 function get(){
   return $http.get('http://localhost/test.php');
 }
 return{get:get};
});

todomvc.controller('TodoCtrl', function TodoCtrl($scope, $location, $filter, todoREST) {
    var todos = $scope.todos = todoREST.get().then(function(data){
    todos = data.data;
    console.log(todos); // Data available here
    });
});
```

I am unable to get the title in the page when it is loaded. What am I doing wrong? And is my approach the right way to make a RESTful call?

Here is a link to what I have done,
http://plnkr.co/edit/kaSCe9HoMPEK1hD4QgJl?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning $scope.todos to the promise returned by the service, not the data from the callback.

Try

```
todoREST.get().then(function(data){
    $scope.todos = data.data;
    console.log($scope.todos); // Data available here
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/C3fbK3NicU7XkdHAbzCr?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, its working. I have defined put(todos) in a similar way but it is coming as undefined. http://plnkr.co/edit/zLNfrvkADtthowaJE98e?p=preview

Comment: You're still not really understanding the concept of promises I think. I don't understand where you get this double assignment from with services. `var todos = $scope.todos = todoStorage.get()...` The service returns a promise, not the todos. You can assign that promise to a variable but you probably don't want to.

Comment: Look at what your factory is returning to see why your put is undefined.